# Python: How to find the second highest number in a list?

Tags: python

```
def second_highest(list):
""" (list of int) -> int
```

How do you find the second highest value from the list of integers without using remove, pop, or sort (which I tried) since I need to use the same list later on?

There will be no duplication of numbers.

```
list.sort()
return list[-2]
```

I tried removing the highest number using max, sorting the list, but since those mutates the list, I can't use them.

Comment: You should really show some code noone here is going to do it for you but  Do you know how to find the largest element? If you do you can do this problem the same way but add another variable for the second largest element.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried? Show us some code. Walk through things conceptually first: to know the second highest number, what do you have to know first? Probably the highest number. How do you find that?

Answer (score 11):

Use the builtin `sorted` oy `mylist`, which will not modify `mylist`(thanks to @Tofystedeth)

```
mylist = [1, 2, 8, 3, 12]
print(sorted(mylist, reverse=True)[1])
```

Comment: Didn't he mention he doesn't want to use any kind of sorting?

Comment: Sorted already returns a new list.  It should be safe to use it on mylist itself instead of mylist[:].  mylist.sort() would be the one that actually modifies mylist.

Comment: To handle duplicate values, convert mylist into set using set(mylist) call and pass it to sorted function.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = [1,2,8,3,12]

largest = None
second_largest = None

for a in data:
    if not largest or a > largest:
        if largest:
            second_largest = largest
        largest = a

print("largest: {}".format(largest))
print("second_largest: {}".format(second_largest))
```

Comment: Your code will not work in some cases. Consider `[25, 98, 74, 11, 89]` it'll return wrong second_largest value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 arr = [2, 3, 4, 2, 4, -3, 43, -4, -25, 45, 9]
 my_list = list(set(arr))
 my_list.sort()
 if len(my_list) == 1:
     print(my_list[0])
 elif len(my_list) >= 2:
     print(my_list[-2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nums=[1,2,3,3,5,4,5,5,2]

#making new set to maintain uniqueness
new_list= set(nums)

high= max(nums)
new_list.remove(high)
print(max(new_list))

#This code uses remove but does not do any changes to the given list
print(nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer is more simple and more readable for beginners

```
x=[2,3,4,2,5,9,8,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,1,3,4,5]

max=-10000000
for i in x:
    if(i>max):
        secondmax=max
        max=i
    elif(i>secondmax and i!=max):
        secondmax=i
    
        
print(secondmax)
```

Comment: Just do 1 pass and track 2 max numbers

Answer (score 1):

**##This will work even if numbers are negative. Logic is : convert the list() to set() and back to list to use the sort() method and then print the -2 position value in the list. This gives you the second-highest value.## "Python 3"**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
    z = list(set(arr))
    z.sort()
    print(z[-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [2, 3, 4, 2, 4, -3, 43, -4, -25, 45, 9]

arr = array.copy()

z = max(arr)

# if list contains duplicate max elements removing them until We get Second highest

while max(arr) == z:
  arr.remove(max(arr))

print(max(arr))
print(array)
```

Comment: The OP wrote *"...without using remove..."* and you post an answer with `remove`?

Comment: trincot try this code, it won't mutate the list. op asked for code that donot mutate the list.

Comment: I agree it does not mutate the list.

Comment: so is it ok to post this code or should i remove it?

Comment: It could stay. I would just replace `remove(max(arr))` with `remove(z)` to avoid a needless extra traversal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to find the 2nd largest number in the list without using any inbuilt functions.

```
data = [11,22,1,2,5,67,21,32]

max1 = data[0] # largest num
max2 = data[1] # second largest num


for num in data:
    if num > max1:
        max2 = max1 # Now this number would be second largest
        max1 = num # This num is largest number in list now.
    
    # Check with second largest
    elif num > max2:
        max2 = num # Now this would be second largest.

print(max2)
```

Comment: It would be better if you could explain your code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using sort. However, it gives you the possibility to reuse the list since you are temporarily storing the list ***arr*** in ***sortedArr***. Calling ***arr*** by itself would return the original list. Here you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLBboMwDIbveQpLvVAJoWrVdqjEoZdpk3aYtN2qSk3BQNQsYU7o6F6eJQHK6KTBgRDb3//bSX2xlVbrrlvAo1C5UCVwoEYpJGhqUM3H0a2EcrsvwljQBWyJ@MWwBbxhplUOlSgrdKHfudLlMsaJIIXdXbyOH9x7v2dGk8V8G/b7deSSYsIzksH0nRpcgnsc3EW9G1shcK/owTmaDHuXmnKkhI3iI86hd6u9B2yNEaUK9WPSmcsGPWeCWh1@zpwEP0qEw5B7SJgJ7T1dBVbB17MSVnApvkdzU@ms4ODRq4QxVmiC1qtGV4vLTc@ySHzoknRTVgHYZw3@uBtwVmF28lmiGBRDGwbws@FybGHWZALMj1EUUQtpOsaWm7DrH@fUCTtMb6QAYR0x9p8vIeUUH@gK2zkapcEJdzurdoYFpe2E5tPB9J38OYObQV5VjoT8FMj9SjfhQvpiqXXthl2TUDaa1Q/36dVHpjPzurr4V7frfgA)

```
# Finding a runner up number in a List of Arrays
# Second highest number in a list

arr = [2,3,6,6,5]
sortedArr = sorted(arr,reverse=True)    # Sorting the array in descending order.
highest = sortedArr[0]  # Assign the highest value in the array to the variable `highest`.
secondHighest = 0   # Initializing the variable `secondHighest` to 0.


for x in (sortedArr):   # Iterating through the sorted array and checking if the value is equal to the highest value. 
    if(x == highest):
        continue    # If it is, it will continue to the next value. 
    else:
        secondHighest = x   # If it is not, it will assign the value to the variable `secondHighest` 
        break   # break out of the loop.

print(secondHighest)    # Printing the value of the variable `secondHighest`.

>>> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [2,3,5,1,7,8]
secondhighest = max([i for i in list if i<max(a)])
```

This will give you the second highest value in the list.

Answer (score 0):

in case of list containing multiple highest number we can find the 2nd highest using loop. As we encounter the number lesser than the highest number in the sorted list we print the number and break the loop using the break function. here is the submission.

```
list.sort(reverse = True)
mx = max(list)

for num in list:
    if num < mx:
       print(num)
       break
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

1. Copy unique list elements to another list (if Already the list elements are unique, go to step 2) .
2. You should find the maximum in the list and save its index. Then remove it from the list using the `remove()` function and then find the maximum of the new list (with the original maximum value removed) and that will be your second highest element. You can then use the `insert()` method to add back the original maximum back into the list.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code to find the maximum and second maximum number in a list or array(python). Tried with all the combination of elements(negative and positive), it is working fine. We can optimize this code as i am not using any inbuilt method.
Below is the list combinations this code is tested with:
la = [1,1,1,1,1],la = [1,1,1,1,1,0],la = [5,4,1,2,3],la = [3,6,2,7],la = [1,2,3,4,5],la = [4,5,1,2,3],la = [5,5,4,3,2,1],la = [-1,1,0,0,0],la = [-1,-2,-3,-4], la = [-1,0],la = [-2,-2,-2,-2,0,1,1,1,1]

```
def findSecmax(la):
    mx = la[0]
    sec = 0 # or sec = min(la) or we can take (- sys.maxsize)
    for i in la:
        if i < sec:
            sec = i

    for i in la:
        if i > mx:
            mx = i

    for i in la:
        if i > sec and mx > i:
            sec = i

    if sec == mx:
        return  "we have same elements in the list. So max is {}".format(mx)
    else:
        return mx,sec


print(findSecmax(la))
```